# Slice dataframe and put slices into new colums

Tags: dataframe, slice

i have a big dataframe with 1 million rows of time series data. I want to slice it into smaller chunks of 1000 rows each. So this would give me 1000 chunks, and i need every chunk to be copied into a column of a new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [numpy.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) to achieve this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def create_df_with_slices_in_cols(df, no_of_cols):
    # df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(df_size), columns=['random_nos'])
    df_list = []
    for i, df_split in enumerate(np.array_split(df, no_of_cols)):
        df_split = df_split.rename(columns={'random_nos':f'Slice{i}'})
        df_split.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df_list.append(df_split)

    return pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
    
create_df_with_slices_in_cols(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**6), columns=['random_nos']), 
                              no_of_cols=10**3)
```

Note that if len(df) is not exactly divisible by no_of_cols (e.g: 10 & 3) then one column will have extra numbers.

```py
create_df_with_slices_in_cols(10, 3)

    Slice0      Slice1      Slice2
0   0.955620    0.543234    0.509360
1   0.755157    0.174576    0.267600
2   0.816509    0.776549    0.455464
3   0.990282    NaN         NaN
```

---

**Update**

To minimize the displacement of data when using a column size(say `n`) that doesn't divide len(df) exactly, you can only consider the first `n-1` columns, then create one final column with the remaining rows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(16000), columns=['random_nos'])
df_size = len(df)
slice_size = 2144.14
no_of_cols = int(df_size//slice_size + 1)

def create_df_with_slices_in_cols(df, no_of_cols):
    df_list = []
    for i, df_split in enumerate(np.array_split(df, no_of_cols)):
        df_split = df_split.rename(columns={'random_nos':f'Slice{i}'})
        df_split.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df_list.append(df_split)

    return pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)

# fill out the first 7 (n-1) columns first
rows_first_pass = int((no_of_cols-1) * np.floor(slice_size))
df_combined = create_df_with_slices_in_cols(df[:rows_first_pass], no_of_cols-1)

# fill out the 8th (nth) column using the remaining rows
rem_rows = df_size - rows_first_pass
last_df = df[-rem_rows:].rename(columns={'random_nos':f'Slice{no_of_cols-1}'})
last_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_combined = pd.concat([df_combined, last_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Your code splits the dataframe into 10**3 pieces. I want to break it into pieces of the length X. Your code does the same as 1000*1000 = 1Million, but my dataframe might have different length etc. sorry my example was bad.

Answer (score 0):

i am now doing this, which does the job but might be inefficient. Im still happy if people could help:

```
for df_split in np.array_split(df, len(df) // chunk_size):
  #print(df_split['random_nos'].mean())
  i=i+1
  df_split= df_split.reset_index()
  df_split = df_split.rename({'random_nos': 'String'+str(i)}, axis=1)
  df_all = pd.concat([df_all, df_split], axis=1)
```

Will do. Now that i can slice my dataframe, i run into the next problem. in my timeseries, i want to slice around 16000 events with a duration of 2144.14 samples. If i slice at 2144 or 2145, slices will become displaced more and more. I tried the following, but it didnt work:

```
def slice_df_into_chunks(df_size, chunk_size):
    df_list = []
    chunk_size2=chunk_size
    for i, df_split in enumerate(np.array_split(df3, chunk_size2)):
        df_split = df_split.rename(columns={'ChannelA01':f'Slice{i}'})
        df_split.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df_list.append(df_split)
    
        if i % 6==0:
            chunk_size2=chunk_size-1
            print(i)
        else:
            chunk_size2=chunk_size
    
    return pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
    
df4=slice_df_into_chunks(len(df3), np.floor(EventsPerLog))
```

i thought about solving this issue with something like this (it takes ages), so every now and then the chunk_size is smaller. After i defined the groups, i can cast those into dataframe-columns.

```
for i in range(40):
    df.loc[i*SamplesEvent:(i+1)*SamplesEvent2,'Group']=i
    if i % 6==0:
        SamplesEvent2=SamplesEvent2-1
        print(i)
    else:
        SamplesEvent2=5
```

Comment: It is more efficient to do `pd.concat` just once after processing all the `df_split`s. My updated answer shows how to do this.

Comment: that does the job and is much quicker than my solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on other questions which still don't have answers

Comment: Will do. Now that i can slice my dataframe, i run into the next problem. in my timeseries, i want to slice around 16000 events with a duration of 2144.14 samples. If i slice at 2144 or 2145, slices will become displaced more and more. I tried the following, but it didnt work:

Comment: Sorry, I think I have got the chunk_sizes variable wrong (edited now). Actually that should be the number of columns you need, so: `16000/2144.14 = 7.46`, you will need 8 columns to get all your data. But still if you specify 8, it will displace a lot of data - what you can do is specify 7, then do one extra pass to add all the remaining data to the final column.

Comment: Also, please add what is the larger problem you are trying to solve (avoids [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)), and some representative sample data to your question.